# Cancan not working for new/create with models that belong to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

This is on latest version of cancan and rails. Routine belongs to User and User has many Routines. The following works for listing and editing the correct records

`can :manage, Routine, :user => {:organization_id => user.organization_id}`

but it denies access on new.

Answer (score 0):

The error probably occurred when accessing the new, when there is no organization_id when creating new routines?

Why not just

```
can :manage, Routine
```

Do you have any particular reason?

Comment: They cannot just manage Routine. That would allow them to edit and make routines for anyone. They need to be restricted to just their organization_id, which is in the user model.

Comment: try
can [:create,:new,:edit,:update,:index],[User],:organization_id => user.organization_id